# OAuth Authorization code grant - Docusign - Error response while making calls to generate access and refresh tokens from auth code

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to use authorization code grant flow to authorize to my app Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html). I am building an app to support auto user provisoning to Docusign using REST APIs. i have created a developer account and have obtained Integrator Key and the secret key.

I made following request to obtain the auth code :

```
account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=<localhost>  and the response on the browser with the code.
```

I am using curl command to generate tokens using the following request :

```
 curl -iX POST account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token -H "Authorization: Basic base64_representation_of_clientId:clientSecret" -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=<Auth Code recieved in the previous step>'
```

However I am getting this response :

```
  HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
 Location: account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
 Server: BigIP
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Length: 0
```

What can be the possible reason for this error response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try adding the protocol (https://) to the request URI?

`curl -iX POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token...`